# after upgrading to 3.8.1.1 getting error

Tags: botframework

I upgraded my Microsoft.Bot.Builder to 3.8.1.1.  When I publish now, I am getting the error [19:42:31] -> POST Request to 'http://localhost:3979/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error and the bot always display 'Sorry, my bot code is having an issue'

The program was working fine before the upgrade.  How can I make it work?

The messagecontroller code is

Comment: Debug it locally.

Comment: If you are upgrading from much older versions you then you'd probably check the web.config file to see if there are fields "MicrosoftAppId" "MicrosoftAppPassword" and they are correctly set (in some older versions those keys had different names)

Comment: The web.config has MicrosoftAppID and MicrosoftAppPassword only.  In the emulator, I am getting the following messages

[10:44:05] <- GET 200 getConversationData 
[10:44:05] <- GET 200 getPrivateConversationData 
[10:44:05] <- GET 200 getUserData 
[10:44:05] <- POST 200 setConversationData 
[10:44:05] <- POST 200 setUserData 
[10:44:05] <- POST 200 setPrivateConversationData 
[10:44:05] <- POST 200 Reply[message] Sorry, my bot code is having an issue. 
[10:44:05] -> POST Request to 'http://localhost:3979/api/messages' failed: [500] Internal Server Error

Comment: If you can post the code for your bot, we can look it over and help determine what the issue is.